# Normal Edit Modifier changes scene appearance before pressing Apply, sounds like a bug?

Tags: modifiers, normals

I have only one object in my scene, and is a 3d scanned mesh. Without pressing any settings in the modifier, the mesh changed in appearance right after I click on Normal Edit inside the Modifier menu to add it. I guess the appearance changed because it edited the custom normals, but why it does that before I click on the Normal Edit modifier's Apply button? I am using Blender 2.8.

Does it mean that I can use Normal Edit Modifier without clicking apply? Because if I clicked apply, the mesh looked less smooth.

Comment: That's how all modifiers are supposed to work! Once you've applied them there's no going back (except via CTRL-Z if you haven't saved the blend file). This means that you can, for instance, render a scene and delete or change settings in the modifier and try again if you don't like the result.

Comment: Thanks for your great comment, I am totally new to Blender.